# How to change the color of roads in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I am using Google Maps as a regular user, I am not a developer, I don't need any APIs and such.

I need to change the color of the roads in Google Maps to make them have a gray color, and I can only find an option in Layers - More - Street view that colors them in green, which is a way to strong color for me

Are there any options to customize the colors of the roads, and the color of the borders of the roads, and the colors of railways?

Answer (score 1):

*Are there any options to customize the colors of the roads, and the color of the borders of the roads, and the colors of railways?*

No